# MyFramework.xcodeproj: The operation couldn’t be completed. Exec format error

Tags: xcode

I have changed my workstation, and now I get:

"Failed to launch script /Users/rudi/workspace/MyFramework/MyFramework.xcodeproj: The operation couldn’t be completed. Exec format error"    (in a small window)

I can compile and the App works. Why am I getting this message? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure to save your AppleScript as text from the AppleScript editor. In addition, be sure to set your script to executable: chmod +x yourscript.applescript

Optionally you can disable the script from Xcode debug starts:
File > Preferences > Behaviors > Start > uncheck Run Script